# Store data from input Form AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, forms, object

I want to store the data of the comment and show it in the view and store in db.

I have this form

```
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Add a comment</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="newRole.newAuthor" placeholder="author">
            <input type="date" ng-model="newRole.newDate">
            <input type="file" ng-model="newRole.commentImage">
            <textarea class="form-control metro" ng-model="newRole.newComment"></textarea>
            <h2>{{txtcomment}}</h2> 
        </div>
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="trip.makeComment(newRole)">Comment</button>
```

and want to store the data here

```
this.tripObject.comments = [
    {
        "author": "Ronnie Oliver",
        "date": "05/06/16 01:19 PM",
        "imageURL": "/assets/images/placeholders/user.svg",
        "text": "Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor."
    },
    {
        "author": "Shaggy Rogers",
        "date": "05/06/16 12:48 PM",
        "imageURL": "/assets/images/placeholders/user.svg",
        "text": "Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor."
    }
];
```

> And this is the controller:

```
this.makeComment = function(newRole){
                // $scope.txtcomment = '';
                var newRole = {
                    "author":newRole.newAuthor,
                    "date":$scope.newDate,
                    "imageURL":$scope.commentImage,
                    "text" : $scope.newComment
                 }
                console.log($scope.newRole);



                console.log($scope.tripObject.comentario)


                this.tripObject.comments.push($scope.newRole);
                console.log(this.tripObject.comments);



            };
```

I know that something is wrong with the controller or with the form but I dont know what.

Comment: did you debug it?

Comment: Yes i debug it.

Answer (score 1):

First Declare

$scope.tripObject={comments:[]};

Then declare

$scope.newRole={};

Then on click makeComment in js

$scope.tripObject.comments.push($scope.newRole);

Here newRole is your object all item will push

Answer (score 0):

There's no `$scope.newDate`, etc.-- it's `$scope.newRole.newDate`, right? Although, since you're passing `newRole` in as an argument, you could just do this instead:

```
this.tripObject.comments.push({
  author: newRole.newAuthor,
  date: newRole.newDate,
  imageURL: newRole.commentImage,
  text: newRole.newComment
})
```

(also, you probably shouldn't reassign `newRole` to a new variable with the same name).

Comment: this works! amazing, but what if I need to store that comment in the database? how can i take that previously pushed object and store with a put or post?

Comment: Instead of doing `push` first, you just assign `newRole` to a different variable, then make an ajax post with it and do the `push` in the callback if it is successful.